# Cant put php vairable in html

Tags: php, html, textbox

So for some reason when I try to place my php variable into the value of my textbox in html it breaks it. The following is my code:

```
function inbox() {
        $error = imap_errors();
        $this->msg_cnt = imap_num_msg($this->conn);
        //echo $this->msg_cnt;
        if($this->msg_cnt === 0){
            exit;
        } else {
            $in = array();
            for($i = 1; $i <= $this->msg_cnt; $i++) {
                $in[$i] = array(
                    'index'     => $i,
                    'header'    => imap_headerinfo($this->conn, $i),
                    'body'      => imap_body($this->conn, $i),
                    'structure' => imap_fetchstructure($this->conn, $i)
                );

                if(property_exists($in[$i]['header'], 'subject')){
                    $header = $in[$i]['header'];
                    $subject = $header->subject;
                    $from = $header->senderaddress;

                    if($from === "blah@blah.com"){
                            $this->searchFormatTwelve($in[$i]['body']);
                            $this->move($this->conn, $in[$i]['index'], 'INBOX.Matched');                
                        }else if($subject === "it's a subject"){                            
                            $this->searchFormatTwo($in[$i]['body']);                                                                                
                            $this->move($this->conn, $in[$i]['index'], 'INBOX.Matched');                                
                         }else { $this->move($this->conn, $in[$i]['index'], 'INBOX.NoMatch');} // end if block for subject

              } // end if property exsist subject


            } // end for loop

            $this->inbox();
        } //end else block for seaches if msg_cnt > 0

    } // end inbox()
```

Then for my HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Email Parser</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="parserStyles.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form class="form-horizontal">
        <fieldset>

        <!-- Form Name -->
        <legend style="padding-left:49%";>Parser</legend>

        <!-- Text input-->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="txtMsgCount">Inbox Message Count</label>  
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <input id="txtMsgCount" name="txtMsgCount" value="<?php echo $this->msg_cnt ?>" class="form-control input-md" type="text" readonly>             
            </div>
        </div>
```

So why cant I place my $msg_cnt into the textbox? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: is the page a .php page

Comment: yeah its a .php

Comment: FYI, array indexes should start at 0, not 1.

Comment: What do you see in the value when you use `View Source`?

Comment: Your `inbox()` function seems to have infinite recursion, since it contains `$this->inbox();` at the end of the `else` block.

Comment: Yeah the $this-.inbox(); is there so it can cycle through a few hundred emails before it stops. For some reason the for loop stops after one match or noMatch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code I can't see that `inbox()` function was ever called. So if it's never been executed how can you get a result of its work?

You use `<?php echo $this->msg_cnt ?>`. `$this` is a contextual variable. In what context do you use it?

Your code doesn't work because you're trying to print a non-existent variable (at least I can't see it in the given code).

I can't check how it really works because you didn't provide us with a part of your code that can be executed on a local machine. But I can suggest you to check the following things:

1. Check if your document has `.php` extension;
2. Make yourself sure that needed php function is included above your tries to print anything;
3. Check if your php function returns anything or affect any external data (variables, objects, constants, arrays...);
4. Check if your php function's been executed in any way or will be executed at the moment when you want to print anything;
5. Check if you're trying to print correct value from correct variable.

The best decision would be rewriting of `inbox()` function in a way when it returns anything (`$this->msg_cnt` for example). After that you can try `<?php echo inbox(); ?>`.

Comment: added in some code so you can now see what happens in the inbox(). Also this is a function thats called from another file that is also a .php

Comment: @agates, `$this` is a reference to the current object. What is the current object in `<?php echo $this->msg_cnt ?>`?

Comment: Yeah I got utterly stupid there. no idea why I had the $this in there. Maybe I dont code running off of 2 hrs sleep.

Comment: Try to print correct value and text here if it works or not.